# Why i can not pass response data to redux store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am having trouble to dispatch component state value to redux store .My idea is that i will dispatch to redux store only API response data and after can access it from different screens:

When i try it , i am getting error:  ReferenceError: action is not defined
    at loginSuccessful (http://packager.yz-9ze.anonymous.easy…}

Here is my component code:

```
import { loginSuccessful } from "../../redux/actions/loginacction";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: {
        login: "",
        password: ""
      },
      activity: false,
      response: {},
      showpassword: true
    };
  }

  _login = async () => {
    if (this.state.user.login !== "" && this.state.user.password !== "") {
      console.log(this.state);
      this.setState({ activity: true });
      try {
        await Axios.post(LoginAPI, this.state, {
          headers: { appversion: 1.4 }
        })
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            const status = response.status;
            if (status === 200) {
              this.setState({ activity: false });
              this.setState({ response: response.data });
              const userData = this.state.response;
              this.props.dispatch(loginSuccessful(userData));
              //this.props.login_api_call;
              //this.props.navigation.navigate("CreateMove");
              console.log(this.state);
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log({ error });
            this.setState({ activity: false });
            Alert.alert("Error", error.response.data.error);
          });
      } catch (error) {}
    } else {
      Alert.alert("Support", "Enter Email and Password");
    }
  };

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    userData: state.loginCredentialsReducer
  };
};

// const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
//   return {
//     login_api_call: userData => dispatch(loginSuccessful(userData))
//   };
// };
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Login);
```

Here is my action type and creator:

```
export const LOGINSUCCESSFUL = "LOGINSUCCESSFUL";

export const loginSuccessful = userData => {
  console.log(action);
  return {
    type: LOGINSUCCESSFUL,
    payload: userData
  };
};
```

And here is my reducer

```
import {LOGINSUCCESSFUL} from "../actions/actiontypes";

const initialState = {
  userData: {}
};

const loginCredentialsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGINSUCCESSFUL:
      return {
        ...state,
        userData: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default loginCredentialsReducer;
```

Comment: `import { loginSuccessful } from "../../redux/actions/loginacction";`  maybe you have a typo  `import { loginSuccessful } from "../../redux/actions/loginaction";`

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `console.log(action)` here, but `action` isn't declared anywhere. Hence the error.

```js
export const LOGINSUCCESSFUL = "LOGINSUCCESSFUL";

export const loginSuccessful = userData => {
  console.log(action); // <-- action is not declared anywhere
  return {
    type: LOGINSUCCESSFUL,
    payload: userData
  };
};
```

Comment: i removed console.log(action), but it is still complain and gives the same error

Comment: If you open that file in the devtools sources panel, do you see the change that you made? If it's still saying `ReferenceError: action is not defined at loginSuccessful` then either your change didn't load or you're looking at the wrong file or the wrong site. If you click on the error in the console does it show you the relevant source?

Comment: It worked fine, once i restarted expo. Now i see that i dispatch response data to redux store.Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

In this:

```
export const loginSuccessful = userData => {
  console.log(action);
  return {
    type: LOGINSUCCESSFUL,
    payload: userData
  };
};
```

you never defined action hence the error.

Comment: i removed  console.log(action) and still receive same error